# Node JS Bluetooth Module installation error

Tags: node.js, npm, bluetooth

I am receiving error while installing NPM Bluetooth module. I have already installed node-gyp but still receiving error:

```
132 verbose stack Error: node-bluetooth@1.2.6 install: `node-gyp configure build`
132 verbose stack Exit status 1
132 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
132 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
132 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
132 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
132 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
132 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
133 verbose pkgid node-bluetooth@1.2.6
134 verbose cwd C:\Users\Dr Padma srinivas\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs
135 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
136 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "node-bluetooth"
137 verbose node v12.13.0
138 verbose npm  v6.12.0
139 error code ELIFECYCLE
140 error errno 1
141 error node-bluetooth@1.2.6 install: `node-gyp configure build`
141 error Exit status 1
142 error Failed at the node-bluetooth@1.2.6 install script.
142 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
143 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! "There is likely additional logging output above" -- did you check the output above? Can you post what that says?

Comment: The above is from the actual log file that got generated. It huge am not able to copy it here.